# Required Brand wise data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

[image: I have required count of data name wise, Senario 1 and 2 consider, brand wise good and bad data. I used Excel 2013, guide me which formula is used for this criteria.]

I have required count of data name wise, Senario 1 and 2 consider, brand wise good and bad data.
I used Excel 2013, guide me which formula is used for this criteria.

I try countif + index + match formula but don't work. i expecting get data thru excel formula in Excel 2013.

Comment: Feb Month Data need to be consider

Comment: Pls supply to the ones who want to help copiable data, and try to keep to the SO recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As @Blackcat suggested - could you edit your question and include the data in a format that can be copy/pasted.  [This](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) link is useful for creating those tables.  The `Edit` button is at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it in `Excel 2013`:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C25</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($D$3:$AG$17,,MATCH(1,
 N(LOOKUP(2,1/($C$23:C$23<>""),$C$23:C$23)&"|"&$C22=
 LOOKUP(COLUMN($D$1:$AG$1),COLUMN($D$1:$AG$1)/($D$1:$AG$1<>""),$D$1:$AG$1)&"|"&$D$2:$AG$2),0))=C$24)*
 ($A25=$C$3:$C$17)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$3:$B$17,{1,2},0))))
```

---

- Two `LOOKUP()` functions is used for the `Brand` Rows in order to fill the blanks for the respective months.
- Using `Ampersand` --> `&` with a delimiter to combine with the `LOOKUP()` function outputs, to match with the column positions.
- The above is used in `INDEX()` functions **[column_num]** to get the respective column values, i.e. `Good`, `Bad,` Awesome` etc.
- The above is next compared with the one in the output range and name is compared withits respective column in the source.
- Using `ISNUMBER()` & `MATCH()` function to get the desired positions of scenario in the source, wrapping within the former to return `TRUE` or `FALSE`
- Lastly, wrapping the whole within a `SUMPRODUCT()` function to get the sum of the matrixes multiplications of `TRUE` & `FALSE` of the corresponding arrays.
- Also, note depending ones excel version it may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode. And this is done.

---